# Trim trailing and leading slash in bash - joining param substitutions?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to trim a possible `/` from the start and end of a string in bash.

I can accomplish this via the following:

```
string="/this is my string/"
string=${string%/}
string=${string#/}
echo $string # "this is my string"
```

However, I would like to know if there's a way to join those two lines (2 + 3) to replace both at once. Is there a way to join the substitution, or is that the best I'm going to get?

Comment: Are your `/`s always at the beginning and the end?

Comment: They can be, but it isn't guaranteed. I also need to persist slashes inside the string.

Comment: Note that your 1st assignment as currently written (`string=/this is my string/`), is syntactically invalid - you need quotes around the value.

Comment: @mklement0 yeah was just a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do that. However if you're sure that your string begins in / and ends in / you can trim it by `${P:M:N}` format:

```
string='/this is my string/'
string=${string:1:(-1)}
```

Adding a check could also help but it's still two statements:

```
[[ $string == /*/ ]] && string=${string:1:(-1)}
```

Note: Solution is only available starting Bash 4.2.

Answer (score 27):

Coming to this very late... You can use bash variable substitution. It can remove a leading OR trailing optional slash, but it can't do both at the same time. If we execute:

```
VAR1=/one/two/
VAR2=one/two
echo ${VAR1} ${VAR2}
echo ${VAR1#/} ${VAR2#/}
echo ${VAR1%/} ${VAR2%/}
```

then we get:

```
/one/two/ one/two            # No change
one/two/ one/two             # No leading slashes
/one/two one/two             # No trailing slashes
```

As we can see, slashes inside the variables remain unaltered.

You can combine them using an intermediate variable as:

```
VAR3=${VAR1#/}               # Remove optional leading slash
VAR3=${VAR3%/}               # Remove optional trailing slash
echo ${VAR3}
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question exactly? This does exactly what the question already suggests, but they explicitly ask for a solution in a single statement. This just copies the problem statement.

Comment: Because it states that it can't be done in a single statement, but it's much lighter weight than any of the piping solutions. It also works when either of the slashes is missing.

Comment: Output in the second code block is wrong. The output column two should always be `one/two`

Comment: @austinheiman - point noted and fixed. I think it was something that got missed in the editing. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use `sed` you could do:

```
string="/this is my string/"
echo $string | sed 's/^\/\(.*\)\/$/\1/g'
```

This assumes the slashes are at the beginning and/or end of the string

Comment: Nice, and it should persist slashes within the string right? Is this the fastest method?

Comment: It only strips slashes at the beginning `^` operator and at the end `$` operator. If it is the fastest I don't know, you should test this yourself

Comment: fastest is going to be the two lines in the question itself.  Avoid forks.  Anyway:  res=$(echo "/what ever/" | sed 's@^/@@;s@/$@@') -- avoid the backslashes, too.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives If you can do `string=${string%/}; string=${string#/}` you better choose it over `sed` It's way faster than forking and piping. Also this is still a two statement process.

Answer (score 3):

Another pure `bash` solution (v3.2 or above), using `=~` for regex matching and the special `$BASH_REMATCH` array variable to reference capture group results.

```
string='/this is my string/'
[[ $string =~ ^/(.*)/$ ]] && string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

`$string` is left untouched if its value is not enclosed in `/`.

Answer (score 2):

If your `/`s are always at the start and end

```
echo "${string//\/}"
this is my string
```

If not

```
string="/this is /my string/"
IFS=/ read -ra x <<<"$string"
(IFS=/; printf '%s\n' "${x[*]:1:${#x[*]}-1}")
this is /my string
```

Or

```
echo "$(IFS=/; set -- $string; printf '%s\n' "${*:2:$#-1}")"
this is /my string
```

Comment: `${string//\/}` removes all the slashes, not the leading or trailing.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
truncate_leadingSlash()
{
 local string="$1"
 local len=${#string}
 while [[ "${string:$(expr $len - 1)}" == "/" ]]
 do
  string=${string:0:$(expr $len - 1)}
  len=${#string}
 done
 echo $string
}

truncate_leadingSlash "Autobiography/Of/Yogi//////"
```

Output: "Autobiography/Of/Yogi"